# Determine the Carry, Zero and Sign flag with cmp?

Tags: assembly, x86

Determine the Carry, Zero and Sign flag with cmp?

```
mov al, 5
cmp al, 7
```

The carry flag is set to 1, the zero flag is set to 0 and the sign flag is set to 1.

5-7 = -2, so I understand why the sign flag will be turned on and the zero flag will be the same, but why is the carry flag turned on?

From my understanding, a carry flag is turned on when there is an unsigned integer overflow. I'm not really understanding how that applies here.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, cmp is the same as sub, except that the result is not stored in a register. The flags are the same in both cases though.

Comment: When using 8 bit arithmetic `5-7=254` so there is an unsigned overflow. Suggested reading: [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: @jester unsigned overflow from 254 makes sense. Where did you get 254 from?

Comment: got it. 00000101 - 00000111 = 11111110

Comment: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt